# Wold's decomposition and Gaussian distribution in infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: autoregressive, vector-autoregression

It is well known that the [Wold's decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem) allows that every covariance-stationary time series $ Y_{{t}}$  can be written as the sum of two time series one deterministic $\eta _{t}$ and one stochastic$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }b_{j}\varepsilon _{t-j}$.

$ Y_{t}=\eta _{t}+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }b_{j}\varepsilon _{t-j}$

(see wikipedia for details)

If $\varepsilon _{t}$ is an uncorrelated sequence in terms of a white noise process it means that we are explaining $Y_{t}$ as a linear combination of an infinite number of white noise vectors, $\varepsilon _{t-i}$ for $i$ that goes to infinity, each one with variance finite and equal to the identity matrix.

My question is, how could this theorem be consistent with the idea that [canonical Gaussian distribution in infinite dimensional Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44324/why-dont-we-allow-the-canonical-gaussian-distribution-in-infinite-dimensional-h) does not exist?

Am I allowd to write the joint distribution of the infinite number of white noise vectors?

Comment: I am wondering how relevant the `var` tag is.

Comment: Hi @richard-hardy the Wold decomposition is intrinsically linked to the VAR model (Vector Autoregressive model) of which it is a representation in terms of an infinite moving average process.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @richard-hardy  you are welcome